# Arduino and PHP through WiFi

Tags: php, arduino, xampp

How to send the data in the PHP web page through WiFi connection? I'm having trouble of using `GET` and `POST`.

Arduino Code :

```
Serial.println("Starting connection to server . . .");

Adafruit_CC3000_Client client = cc3000.connectTCP(ipAddress, 80);  
if(client.connected()){      
  client.println("POST  /vsample.php HTTP/1.1");      
  client.println("Host: localhost");      
  client.println("Content-Type:  Application/x-www-form-urlencoded");      
  client.println("Content-Length: 100");     
  client.println("");      
  client.println("Real power = ");
  client.print(realPower);
  Serial.println("POSTED!");
  delay(10000);      
  Serial.println("Connected and Data Sent");
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['realPower'])){
    echo $_POST['realPower'];
  }

?>
```

Comment: the content-length should be the real length of you payload!

Comment: Yeah, no problem with that. I just want to throw the data in the internet

Comment: You need a delay after connectTCP or a while loop to wait the TCP connection.

Comment: and no spaces in your payload. client.print("realPower=");
client.print(realPower); But you still need to fix the length

Comment: Going to change the code, because our target is to get the real time readings using Ajax. I tried to run this and the server is responding but not displaying anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249173/problems-connecting-cc3000-wifi-shield-and-arduino-using-ajax